# Java API to access Mainframe remotely

Tags: java, api, interface, remote-access, mainframe

I am looking for a java API to access mainframe remotely. I am looking for something similar to JTOpen or IBM Toolbox for iseries systems. Through this API, I should be able to connect to the mainframes and fetch information from the mainframe, something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Mainframe myMainframe = new Mainframe(ipAddress, userName, password);
    myMainframe.connect();
    System.out.println(myMainframe.getSystemName);
    myMainframe.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html). It's provide API for building distributed systems. I belive it can be used in your Mainframe environment. It's server-client model. You can write interface like:

```
public interface MainframeMXBean {
    public String getName();
}
```

and implement it in your Mainframe class, then create proxy for local usage:

```
MainframeMXBean remoteMF = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(connection, jmxName, MainFrameMXBean.class);
System.out.println(remoteMF.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java Management Extensions (JMX) should be sufficiently widespread and generic to satisfy your need.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/examples.html) is an official online example set. Also, you can find an O'Reilly [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002459) about it.